# Jquery/javascript datetime

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

i want to convert this string 23/08/2009 12:05:00 
   to javascript datetime

how can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the parts of the date using a regex, and call the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor, adjusting the month number, since the month numbers are zero based, for example:

```
function customDateParse (input) {
  var m = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(m[2], m[1] - 1, m[0], m[3], m[4], m[5]);
}

customDateParse('23/08/2009 12:05:00');
// Sun Aug 23 2009 12:05:00
```

If you don't like regexps:

```
function customDateParse (input) {
  input = input.split(' ');
  var date = input[0].split('/'),
      time = input[1].split(':');

  return new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0], time[0], time[1], time[2]);
}

customDateParse('23/08/2009 12:05:00');
// Sun Aug 23 2009 12:05:00
```

But if you find that complex and you are willing to do more Date manipulations I highly recommend you the [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) library, small, opensource and syntactic sugar...

Comment: That seems a bit complex. It also seems like an over use of Regex since there is a `getDateFromFormat()` method available in JavaScript.

Comment: See the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use momentjs to convert from string to Date object.

```
var date = '23/08/2009 12:05:00';
var datetime = moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
datetime = moment.toDate();
```