# javascript date conversion

Tags: javascript, date

I want to take an existing javascript string and convert it javascript timestamp object, 
then store as format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

```
mystring = "Mon Nov 07 2011 09:20:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)";
var timeObject = new Date(mystring);
```

Comment: Sweet, you know what you want. Now what is your question?

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317177/jquery-javascript-datetime

Comment: Instead of editing your own question and including the answer, consider **answering your own question** as you normally would answer someone else's question. Then accept your own answer. This will make it easier for others to find your problem and solution. It may also earn you some upvotes and reputation.

Comment: Truth - stupid system won't let me. Not enough air miles. This site is great but maintained by a bunch of nanies with too much time on their hands.  Appreciate if you can do it for me.  Thanks

Comment: Why vote down? Read the difinition of vote down.

Answer (score 0):

```
// pass in javascript date object, return variations of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS 
function fnFormatDateTime(timeObject)
{
    // construct day/month/year
    var month = timeObject.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10){
        month = "0" + month;
    }               
    var day = timeObject.getDate();
    if (day < 10){
        day = "0" + day;
    }               
    var year = timeObject.getFullYear();    
    var currentDate  = (" " + year +  month + day).trim();
    var currentDateFormatted  = ( year +"-"+  month +"-"+ day);

    // construct current time
    var hours = timeObject.getHours();
    if (hours < 10){
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }   
    var minutes = timeObject.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10){
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    var seconds = timeObject.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10){
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }               
    var currentTime  = (hours +  minutes + seconds + " ").trim();
    var currentTimeFormatted  = (hours +":"+ minutes +":"+ seconds);

     var retArray = new Array();     
        retArray[0] = (currentDateFormatted + " " + currentTimeFormatted);      
        retArray[1] = (currentDate+ " " + currentTime);             
        retArray[2] = currentDate;      
        retArray[3] = currentTime;
    return retArray;    
}
```

Comment: Moved the solution from the question body down to an answer.